# mysql dynamic insertion

Tags: mysql, sql

In sql command:

```
INSERT INTO table(id,name) VALUES('&id','&name');
```

Reads the values of `id`, `name` dynamically and inserts into the table.
I was trying to implement this query in `MySql` but I got error.
What is the right way to implement this query in `MySql`?

Comment: error: check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right systax to use near '&id','&name');

Comment: Are you executing this directly in MySQL? In PHP? Something else?

Comment: executing in mysql command line client.

Comment: I would try doing the same thing with plain values, e.g.
`INSERT INTO mytable (id, name) VALUES ('a', 'b');`

Possible problems: 
name of table ("table" is a reserved keyword),
ampersand (&) has a special meaning in shell,
quotes might be of the wrong kind - depending on what you used to quote the entire query (It would help if you'd show the code in context of the script)

Comment: In sql it worked ,but in mysql same query is not working (all sql queries worked perfectly in mysql but not this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are inserting data into MySQL through command line or a tool like Workbench or HeidiSQL, just use:

```
INSERT INTO table(id,name) VALUES('some-string','some-string');
```

If you are entering data through PHP, it is advisable to use PDO and bound parameters like so:

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'test', 'test');
$sql = 'insert into table(id, name) values (:id, :name)';

// Notice that we aren't giving any values yet.
// We are just putting placeholders called :id and :name in the query

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
if ($statement === false) {
    echo 'statement didnt work';
    exit();
}

// get your data from somewhere
$id = 12;
$name = 'guru';

try {
    $result = $statement->execute(array(':id'=>$id, ':name'=>$name));

    // in the above statement, we execute the statement
    // during execution we provide a valid id and name to the 
    // placeholders :id and :name, respectively

    if ($result === false) {
        $error = $statement->errorInfo();
        print_r($error);
    }
    else {
        print_r($result);
        echo 'Inserted', "\n";
    }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Hopefully this will help you get going with your insert statements.

Comment: i dont know php so,please explain this,In sql there is a query to read values for records from user and insert into table.In mysql same query it is not working

Comment: It appears that you are expecting MySQL to prompt you for values. MySQL will not prompt you. You will have to use a programming language like C#, Python, php etc. to simulate promoting.

Comment: you are right...!.Actually it worked perfectly in sql so,i expected the same query to work in mysql as all other queries worked perfectly.  thank you